# Loading a YML file in Rails, and maybe using a i18n file instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, rails-i18n, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a dropdown.yml file that stores all my dropdown values for my multi-select fields in my forms. It is not environment dependent, so I do not have :development, :production, etc.

I would like cache the file into a constant so I can use across my app.  I found this command.

```
config = Rails.application.config_for(:payment)
```

However, it looks like it is environment dependent. What is the best way to add the yml?

Second, should I use locales for this instead of a custom yml file?

#### config/dropdown.yml

```
dropdown:
  car_model:
    field1:
      yes: true
       no: false
    region:
      US: United States
      CA: Canada
```

#### Also, is there a way to have a dropdown accessible from multiple names?

```
dropdown:
  car_model| truck_model| bike_model:
    field1:
      yes: true
       no: false
    region:
      US: United States
      CA: Canada
```

So that I could reference field1, from any of the name keys, car_model, truck_model, or bike_model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would make a utility class and module for this. Something like:

```
module DropdownExt

  def self.extended(receiver)
    receiver.each do |k,v|
      define_method(k) do 
        v.is_a?(Hash) ? v.extend(DropdownExt) : v
      end
    end
  end

end

class Dropdowns

  class << self

    private

    def dropdowns_spec
      YAML.load_file("#{path}").with_indifferent_access
    end

    def path
      Rails.root.join("spec/so/dropdowns/dropdowns.yaml") # <== you'll need to change this
    end

  end

  dropdowns_spec[:dropdown].each do |k,v|
    define_singleton_method k do 
      v.extend(DropdownExt)
    end
  end

  %i(
    truck_model
    bike_model
  ).each do |to_alias|
    singleton_class.send(:alias_method, to_alias, :car_model)
  end

end
```

Then you can do:

```
Dropdowns.car_model
 => {"field1"=>{true=>"true", false=>"false"}, "region"=>{"US"=>"United States", "CA"=>"Canada"}}
Dropdowns.truck_model
 => {"field1"=>{"yes"=>"true", "no"=>"false"}, "region"=>{"US"=>"United States", "CA"=>"Canada"}}
Dropdowns.bike_model
 => {"field1"=>{"yes"=>"true", "no"=>"false"}, "region"=>{"US"=>"United States", "CA"=>"Canada"}}
```

Wherever you like.

You'll notice I extended the model hash with a custom `DropdownExt`, so you can also do:

```
Dropdowns.car_model.field1
 => {"yes"=>"true", "no"=>"false"}
Dropdowns.car_model.field1.yes 
 => "true"
Dropdowns.car_model.region.US
 => United States
```

When you do `extend(SomeModule)` on an instance, then only that instance is extended with the module so you don't polute `Hash` (in this case) throughout your entire application.

IMO, using `config` seems a little too low-level. But, I realize that's a matter of personal preference. Also, this will save you a little typing.

Another advantage of this approach is that you get the class methods for each of your models "for free". So you can do:

```
Dropdowns.car_model
```

instead of

```
Rails.application.config.dropdown[:car_model]
```

I don't know. That just seems nicer to me.

Finally, I guess I like encapsulating the whole thing in a class. Again, a matter of personal preference. But, that seems more ruby-ish to me.

BTW, my YAML was wanting to change your `yes` and `no` to `true` and `false`. So, I did:

```
---
dropdown:
  car_model:
    field1:
      'yes':  'true'
      'no':   'false'
    region:
      US: United States
      CA: Canada
```

Which returned

```
{"field1"=>{"yes"=>"true", "no"=>"false"}, "region"=>{"US"=>"United States", "CA"=>"Canada"}}
```

Comment: I really like this. Is there a way in my yml file to may a specific dropdown accessible from multiple methods?  See above update.

Comment: Sure. I updated my answer to give you `Dropdowns.truck_model` and `Dropdowns.bike_model`. Instead of handling it in the `YAML` file, I aliased the class methods. (Doesn't this seem like the right answer? ;-))

Comment: How would you treak it to do Dropdowns.car_model.field1.yes, I assume a recursive function of some type?

Comment: Updated my answer. Seriously, shouldn't this be the accepted answer?

Comment: Glad it helped. BTW, thinking about it a little more, I think it's more spiffy to use a module to extend the functionality rather than using a wrapper class. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190390/discussion-between-user2012677-and-jvillian).

Answer (score 1):

Load it in your application.rb, inside the config block:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  ...
  config.dropdowns = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'dropdown.yml')))
  ...
end
```

use in code via `Rails.application.config.dropdown[:key]

note: I would drop the top level dropdown key, or add that on the end of the load line so you don't need to invoke it every time you want the config. e.g.

```
HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'dropdown.yml')))[:dropdown]
```

Could also just chuck it in a constant in your application.rb:

```
MY_CONST = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'dropdown.yml')))
```

Comment: What do you think about using i18n to manage the dropdown values?

Comment: Only use i18n for translations of them, NOT the data you store.

Comment: i.e. use the dropdown.yml as the values that go into your database and run the values through i18n to translate them on screen only.